# Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from char string

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I received a file and I'm trying to clean the data by inserting this previous table into a new table. Most of the columns should have 'Y' or 'N' but some cells are empty and I'm giving them a value of N. When running the queries, I get Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string. Last activity has date set up this way:  8/23/2018  8:44:00 PM

This is the table that I have: Email_Roster:

```
 [ID_NUM] [INT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [key] [VARCHAR](50) NOT NULL,
 [2017_SL2_s] [VARCHAR](50) NOT NULL,
 [2017_SL2_o] [VARCHAR](50) NOT NULL,
 [2017_SL2_c] [VARCHAR](50) NOT NULL,
 [2017_SL2_b] [VARCHAR](50) NOT NULL,
 [2017_SL2_u] [VARCHAR](50) NOT NULL,
 [last_activity_date] [datetime] NULL,
 [last_email] [VARCHAR](50) NULL,
```

This is the query that I wrote to replace the empty cells but get an error of failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[training] 
     (
       [2017_SL2_s]
      ,[2017_SL2_o]
      ,[2017_SL2_c]
      ,[2017_SL2_b]                        
      ,[2017_SL2_u]
      ,[last_activity_date]
      ,[last_email_date]
       )

    SELECT
        ISNULL ([2017_SL2_s], 'N') [2017_SL2_s],
        ISNULL ([2017_SL2_o], 'N') [2017_SL2_o],
        ISNULL ([2017_SL2_c], 'N') [2017_SL2_c],
        ISNULL ([2017_SL2_b], 'N') [2017_SL2_b],
        ISNULL ([2017_SL2_u], 'N')[2017_SL2_u],
        [last_activity_date], 
         [last_email]
        FROM [dbo].[Email_Roster]
```

Comment: Are you sure yo uare using the MySQL Server database for this?

Comment: I'm using sql and not MySQL

Comment: You should **NOT** store a date (`last_activity_date`) as a string in your table - use the **most appropriate** datatype - **always** - so this would be a `DATE` or a `DATETIME2(n)` datatype for this

Comment: Then PLEASE dont use irrelevant TAGS

Comment: You have a capital D for Date in the table and lower case d in the insert. **Edit** And you already fixed it ^_^

Comment: Not enough information.   What are you selecting FROM?   What are the datatypes, and sample data in the source?   Your INSERT column list starts with a comma, which is a syntax error.   Show your actual code.

Comment: Something does not match here. You posted DDL for Email_Roster but your query only selects from that table. Therefore we can conclude that at least one of your "sl2" columns is being stored in a column (of dbo.Training) whose datatype is date (or datetime). So - which one is it? Remove the insert portion of that last statement and run just the select part - i'll bet it works without error.

Answer (score 2):

The date string you seem to be receiving is not ANSI compliant so you are going to have to use convert and pass it a date style. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Something like this.

```
select convert(date, '8/23/2018 8:44:00 PM', 110)
```